exponentation of a natural number a to the power of ordinal
I am reading about ordinal exponentation and saw that 2^ω = ω.
I tried to find what a^ω is for a>2 but did not see any answers on web.
However in my mind i think that a^ω = ω for all finite a. Is that right?

Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.

Yes, $\alpha^\omega =\omega$ is correct for all finite ordinals $\alpha > 1$.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_arithmetic#Exponentiation may help

For a limit ordinal $\lambda$ and natural number $2\leq n<\omega$, the exponent $n^\lambda$ is defined to be the supremum
$$ n^\lambda = \sup_{\xi<\lambda}n^{\xi} \left( = \bigcup_{\xi<\lambda}n^\xi\right). $$
In the case of $\lambda=\omega$, we know that $\omega$ is indeed a limit ordinal and so
$$ n^\omega = \sup_{\xi<\omega}n^{\xi} = \sup\{ n^\xi \mid \xi < \omega \}.$$
The set $S= \{n^{\xi} \mid \xi < \omega\}$ consists of all powers of $n$, which is a subset of the naturals $\omega$. Hence
$$ n^\omega =\sup S \leq \sup \omega =  \omega. \tag{1} $$
But for any natural number $k<\omega$, we have $k \leq n^k \in S$ and so
$$ n^\omega =\sup S \geq \sup \omega =  \omega. \tag{2} $$
Combining (1) and (2), properties of the $\leq$ ordering gives that $n^\omega = \omega$.
